# How to save variable value across different REST api call using Java core

Tags: java, rest, global-variables, singleton

I have a requirement to hold user list inmemory. The state of user list should maintain across different REST api calls. Like there is an api to save user, so whenever i call save, user saved in variable and will be available in anothee REST api get call.

How can i achieve this? I am thinking of some singleton class to hold data as singleton scope is at JVM level

Answer (score 0):

`REST architecture` which means Representational `State transfer` which means you do not store the state of the object (or `resource`) in REST terms.

Every API hit is (and should be) considered a new resource manipulation call. For e.g. You may be `Creating` a resource (`POST`) , `deleting` a resource (`DELETE`) , `updating` a resource (`PUT`) and so on...

You may still want to access a resource's state i.e. in your case `userlist` which you may somehow update and get from `database` or `file` or `temporary` storage. Database would be preferred.

Your question inclines more towards maintaining `sessions` which is in contrary to REST API `principles`

*I'd suggest you to go through basic principles of REST API architecture* **( Precisely 6 of them)**

https://restfulapi.net/

Comment: I know the REST is stateless, so I asked about storage options other than the database using core Java.